# Error inflating class fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Main activity with two master detail Fragments.I am trying to implement like ["Multiple fragments, multiple activities"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments) method.

**layout** folder
**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MoneyActivity"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container" >
 <fragment class="com.mysite.money.AFragment"
              android:id="@+id/AFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

**layout-large** folder **activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MoneyActivity"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


   <fragment class="com.mysite.money.AFragment"
              android:id="@+id/AFragment"
              android:layout_width="@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <fragment class="com.mysite.money.BFragment"
              android:id="@+id/BFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

**I got error like below(when run on tablet-layout-large):**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mysite.money/com.mysite.money.MoneyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
```

I checked class names of fragments properly.

**I think i got error BFragment**

**BFragment:**
    public class BFragment extends SherlockFragment {

```
    String selectedItem="";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int size = getArguments().size();
        if(size>0)
        {
            selectedItem = getArguments().getString("position").toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView=new TextView(inflater.getContext());
        textView.setText("Selected Item->"+selectedItem);
        return textView;
    }
```

}

**OnItemSelected in my mainActivity(Associated with fragment A)**

```
**@Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
          BFragment displayFrag = (BFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(new BFragment().getId());
        if (displayFrag == null) {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is not in the layout (handset layout),
            // so start DisplayActivity (Activity B)
            // and pass it the info about the selected item
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", id);
            Log.i("innodea", "position->"+id);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is in the layout (tablet layout),
            // so tell the fragment to update
            //displayFrag.updateContent(id);
        }
    }**
```

**AFragment:**

```
public class AFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private View inflate;
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    private int mActivatedPosition= ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

    public interface Callbacks {
        public void onItemSelected(String id);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
     * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
     */
    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
     * given the 'activated' state when touched.
     */
    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
        // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(
                activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                        : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your fragments code and the logcat error

Comment: I am having the same issue.. Did u get it working? Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840128/android-fragments-2-fragment-1-frame-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line: #... Error inflating class fragment` might happen if you manipulate with `getActivity()` inside your fragment before `onActivityCreated()` get called. In such case you receive a wrong activity reference and can't rely on that.

For instance the next pattern is wrong:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout..., container, false);

    Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id...);
    button.setOnClickListener(...); - another problem: button is null

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding Unique ID for the Static Fragment is required. I found it after carefully looking in Logs for error. CLick on below link to see error details:

[Error Inspection in logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN6Tk.png)

No need for FragmentActivity as suggested in many posts. AppCompatActivity is fine.
So, code like below works just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Customize your Android: " />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.android.android_me.ui.MasterListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/StaticFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment code is most likely broken and simply crashes on creation which ends in failure of inflation. Plant breakpoints on each fragment `onCreateView()` and related methods called in during fragment creation or try to instantiate the fragment by hand (`new AFragment()`) and attaching it to The Layout to see where exactly if fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `Fragment` class from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And in the XML file of the activity where you intend to use this fragment, you need to use:

```
        <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        name="yourpackagname.yourfragmentclass"/>
        //package name here, is the name of folder which is in java directory.
```