# Android Fragments - 2 Fragment & 1 Frame Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to create a layout with three vertical panel - 2 fragments and 1 frame layout. 1st fragment will be a list on selection, 2nd fragment will have different content. on selecting a list item from 2nd fragment, 3rd pane will show the details.

Here's my layout files:

activity_three_pane.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".ActivitySectionList" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frg_section_list"
    android:name="eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.FragmentSectionList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frg_chapter_list"
    android:name="eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.FragmentChapterList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_chapter_detail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_section_list.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frg_section_list"
    android:name="eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.FragmentSectionList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    tools:context=".ActivitySectionList"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

activity_chapter_list.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frg_chapter_list"
    android:name="eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.FragmentChapterList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    tools:context=".ActivityChapterList"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

activity_chapter_detail.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fl_chapter_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityChapterDetail"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

The Java code goes like this:

ActivitySectionList.java

```
public class ActivitySectionList extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentSectionList.Callbacks
```

FragmentSectionList.java

```
public class FragmentSectionList extends ListFragment
```

ActivityChapterList.java

```
public class ActivityChapterList extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentChapterList.Callbacks
```

FragmentChapterList.java

```
public class FragmentChapterList extends ListFragment
```

ActivityChapterDetail.java

```
public class ActivityChapterDetail extends FragmentActivity
```

FragmentChapterDetail.java

```
public class FragmentChapterDetail extends Fragment
```

But the application crashes with Inflate Exception and IllegalStateException. I am trying for the past two day but cant find out where the problem is. If anyone has idea on it, please reply.

Onething I noticed is that it works fine on Phone which takes individual fragment for whole screen. But crashes on Tablet which tries to fit three fragments on the screen. When I debugged, I came to know that FragmentChapterList.java's OnAttach gets called before ActivityChapterList.java's onCreate. That's why, it gives the IllegaltStateException: Activity must implement fragment's callback. so, I tried to implement both the fragments callbacks within ActivitySectionList.java.

like this:

```
public class ActivitySectionList extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentSectionList.Callbacks, FragmentChapterList.Callbacks
```

Then it works fine on Tablet. But, not able to retrieve Chapter List on Phone.

Here's my logcat:

---

```
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam/eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.ActivitySectionList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.ActivitySectionList.onCreate(ActivitySectionList.java:20)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  ... 11 more
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at eam.droid.pt.entholkaappiyam.FragmentChapterList.onAttach(FragmentChapterList.java:84)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:867)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
02-12 14:14:55.858: E/AndroidRuntime(989):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Can anyone please tell me where I mightbe going wrong? If anyone comes across tutorial or example of 3 vertical panel(2 list and 1 detail), please point me to it.

Here's the detailed scenario:

Comment: How exactly are you working with those activities? I hope you're not instantiating them yourself in the activity with the layout `activity_three_pane.xml`.

Comment: I mentioned, ActivitySplash as launcher in Manifest file. Within Java code I start ActivitySectionList and setting the content activity_section_list.xml. For tablets, I have refs.xml under values-sw600dp-land with the line <item name="activity_section_list" type="layout">@layout/activity_three_pane</item>

Comment: And where do you use/start the `ActivityChapterDetail` activity?

Comment: I call that inside call back function of FragmentChapterList. The call back function is defined in ActivityChapterList. I check if it's three pane layout. If so, I use "getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_chapter_detail, frgChapterDetail).commit();" or else, i start is as a normal activity

Comment: In this part of code I think is the problem, but nobody can help you without more code related to this.

Comment: Sure. I can share the whole project code.  how do u want me to share?

Comment: Shall I share in DropBox?

Comment: Wherever you can, Dropbox will be fine.

Comment: Please let me know your dropbox email id

Comment: I don't see why you need my dropbox id. If you don't want to make the project public you could simply send my an email(just append @gmail.com to my stackoverflow username)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24637/discussion-between-karthik-palanivelu-and-luksprog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `activity_three_pane.xml` only gets inflated for tablets, and in the `ActivitySectionList` class. In this case, for tablets, both fragments `FragmentSectionList` and `FragmentChapterList` are inflated as part of your layout, thus you need to implement callbacks for both in `ActivitySectionList`, which is the source of your exception.

This setup seems very convoluted and confusing. I would recommend splitting your activities so you're not overlapping code. This will help you diagnose problems much easier, and clean up your code. Example:

```
public class BookActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentSectionList.Callbacks, FragmentChapterList.Callbacks
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_three_pane);
    }
}

public class ActivitySectionList extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentSectionList.Callbacks
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_section_list);
    }
}
```

Then in whichever activity that calls these activites:

```
if( ( getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK ) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE ) {
    startActivity( new Intent(this, BookActivity.class);
}
else {
    startActivity( new Intent(this, ActivitySectionList.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I just wanted to make sure that both fragment callback should be implemented in the same activity. As I mentioned in the question, it works if i did. And yeah, your way of implementation is clear and makes much sense. Thanks once again.

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu Yes, that is correct. Your activity should handle all callbacks and how new screens should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Is your activity extending FragmentActivity?.. if not try extending FragmentActivity instead of just Activity.

Comment: Yeah.. Please see my edited question. I don't understand why Fragment's OnAttach gets called before its activity's onCreate. And are we not supposed to have individual activities for respective fragments?

Comment: Is the exception you're getting now a "Resource Not Found" Exception?

Comment: Nope. I get Inflate Exception and IllegalStateException.

Comment: You get the `IllegalStateException` even after implementing all the Callbacks? You were right on your update, `ActivitySectionList` needs to implement both Callbacks.

Comment: So u mean to say, i dont need two activities for those two fragments? Just one activity implementing two fragments is enough? If so, how will that work in Phones?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess: Can it be that FragmentActivity (support library) is using Fragment (non-support library)? If that is the case: Ensure that you stick to support library (check imports) or use Android 3+.

Comment: I import like this import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: Check all imports like xxxFragment. Fragments exists in 2 versions in both android 3+ and in the support library. If you mix it you're in deep trouble. Should be easy to check.

Comment: Example android.app.Fragment versus android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Likewise with DialogFragment and ListFragment. Also be sure sure not to mix with FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. Both exist in two versions (android.app and android.support.v4.app).

Comment: Yeah I did that. But still the issue pops up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like FragmentChapterList is extending [android.app.ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) instead of the proper [android.support.v4.app.ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html). I would check your imports in FragmentChapterList to make sure that the ListFragment import is actually the support library version.

Comment: hi, i do "import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;" in both FragmentSectionList.java and FragmentChapterList.java